# django no module name

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

i am trying to set up a project and every time i `runserver` it tells me there is no module named 'views' that i am trying to import to the `urls.py` of the same folder!

```
  from django.conf.urls import url 
  import views
  urlpatterns = [
 'products.views', url(r'^$', ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_list')
```

i tried every possible solution and nothing worked :

```
├───carts
│   ├───migrations
│   └───__pycache__
├───ecommerce
│   └───__pycache__
├───newsletter
│   ├───migrations
│   └───__pycache__
├───orders
│   ├───migrations
│   └───__pycache__
├───products
│   ├───migrations
│   └───__pycache__
├───statics
│   └───our_static
│       ├───css
│       ├───img
│       ├───js
│       └───psd
└───templates
    ├───carts
    ├───orders
    ├───products
    └───registration
```

the views file that i want to import should be under products, i tried setting the `PYTHONPATH` but that didn't work either everything i do it either tells me the module doesn't exist or throws a weird syntax error in the views file `print formset.is_valid()` which i figured is totally unrelated does anyone have an explanation for this?
thank you.

Comment: tree command shows folder structure, not files.

Comment: simply use `from . import views` or if you wanted to import views of some other app use `from app import views`

Comment: `File "C:\ecommerce-django-master\src\products\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
      from .views import *
      File "C:\ecommerce-django-master\src\products\views.py", line 49
       print formset.is_valid()
                ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

this is what it does when i `import` views `from .` weird behaviour isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import views like this:

```
 from .views import *
```

You are using class based views so this method will work.

Comment: tried it also gave me the `File "C:\ecommerce-django-master\src\products\urls.py", line 2, in <module> from .views import * File "C:\ecommerce-django-master\src\products\views.py", line 49 print formset.is_valid() ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error

Comment: Your views correctly imported. You getting this error due to not valid syntax. Show your code ? I will check it. print(formset.is_valid()) write in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Change your urlpatterns to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ProductListView.as_view(template_name="product_list"),),
]
```

That should work.

Comment: But he has problem in importing views. How he will use ProductListView? It will gives the error ProductListView is not defined.

Comment: well originally it used to be `views.ProductListView.as_view` i thought it was the cause of the problem but it did not help that's why i added the first `views`